# Reverting a hunk without refreshing in Magit Diff

Tags: magit

Typing `v` in Magit Diff mode causes an often slow and uncecessary refresh. Can this be avoided?

For example when looking at a diff between a range of commits (say `origin/mater...HEAD`). Typing `v` (A.K.A. `M-x magit-revert-no-commit`) applies the reversed hunk to the worktree. The diff between the commits has not changed, but Magit still refreshes the entire buffer. Even if the diff does change, I often would still like to avoid refreshes when I have large diffs that take minutes to refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately Magit isn't smart enough to notice that there's no need to refresh (and there is not setting to just suppress refreshing altogether). I plan to implement intelligent refresh *one day*™ but better don't hold your breath.